Make filters apply only after another specific filter has been selected in JS
This is my first time writing code. I'm using JS. I'm trying to make it so that on my commerce website, you don't see all of the color options in the filter until you select what color family you want. I've written a couple of different variations of the code, but nothing works. This is just on a wordpress website and I'm trying to add custom code.
Here's what I started with:
// Get references to the select elements
const colorFamilySelect = document.getElementById("colorFamilySelect");
const colorSelect = document.getElementById("colorSelect");

// Listen for changes in the color family select
colorFamilySelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
    const selectedColorFamily = colorFamilySelect.value;

    // Show or hide color options based on the selected color family
    if (selectedColorFamily === "Blue") {
        colorSelect.querySelector('option[value="Aqua"]').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        colorSelect.querySelector('option[value="Aqua"]').style.display = "none";
    }
});

Then after playing around and troubleshooting, I did this:
    // Get references to the select elements
    const colorFamilySelect = document.querySelector(<div class="gspro-c-item-filter__attribute"><h4>Color Family</h4>);
    const colorSelect = document.querySelector(<div class="gspro-c-item-filter__attribute"><h4>Color</h4>;

    // Listen for changes in the color family select
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => (
    ) item-filter.addEventListener("change", function (
        ) const selectedColorFamily = '<input>[name="Color Family"]';
                                        
        // Show or hide color options based on the selected color family
        if (selectedColorFamily === 'option[value="Blue"]') {
            colorSelect.querySelector('option[value="Aqua"]').style.display = "block";
        } else {
            colorSelect.querySelector('option[value="Aqua"]').style.display = "none";
        }
    });


I think that I most likely have the incorrect element names. I pulled them from inspect element on my website. Can you guys please help me?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.
